# send sms through tomcat server using java

Tags: java, tomcat, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to send sms using java by a sms gateway. i found the following code to send sms through `tomcatserver`.[HERE IS SOURCE CODE](http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/24573.html). In my windows xp tomcat is running on port 8084 and while running java class i.e. `sendSMS.java` i am getting following:

```
D:\>javac sendSMS.java
 D:\>java sendSMS
 phone------>8366xxxx
 message---->SendMsg+via+Now.SMS
url string->http://localhost:8084/?PhoneNumber=8366xxxx&Text=SendMsg+via+Now.SMS
Opened Con->sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://localhost:8084/?P
honeNumber=8366xxxx&Text=SendMsg+via+Now.SMS
Get Resp  ->OK
```

`In sendSMS.java i just gave my mobile number and changed url from 8800 to 8084`.

But i am getting no sms in my mobile number +91xxxxxxxxxx. Where i am wrong? Please help

Comment: i have signed up nowsms to use trial version only

Comment: you can also try by downloading trial version, it is just 8.4 mb and sendSMS.java is in that link, i have given in my question, just scroll down and to see that java file

Answer (score 1):

- first try sending from web interface `http://127.0.0.1:8800` you can
  reach by pressing web tab and then access web interface of nowsms
  gateway.You will reach send text message web page give the number of
  the mobile in the TO text box and message in the TEXT textbox submit
  it you will recieving a message from gateway and the will show you
  the count of sent message.

Comment: can you specify in more details please, have you tried it? did it work in your terminal?